# error "extra qualification ‘student::’ on member ‘student’ [-fpermissive] "

Tags: c++, constructor

I am getting an error `extra qualification ‘student::’ on member ‘student’ [-fpermissive]`.
And also why `name::name` such syntax is used in constructor?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
class student
{
 private:
     int id;
     char name[30];
 public:
/*   void read()
     {
        cout<<"enter id"<<endl;
        cin>>id;
        cout<<"enter name"<<endl;
        cin>>name;
     }*/
     void show()
     {
        cout<<id<<name<<endl;
     }
     student::student()
     {
        id=0;
        strcpy(name,"undefine");
     }
};
main()
{
 student s1;
// s1.read();
 cout<<"showing data of s1"<<endl;
 s1.show();
// s2.read();
  //cout<<"showing data of s2"<<endl;
 //s2.show();
}
```

Answer (score 41):

In-class definitions of member function(s)/constructor(s)/destructor don't require qualification such as `student::`.

So this code,

```
 student::student()
 {
    id=0;
    strcpy(name,"undefine");
 }
```

should be this:

```
 student()
 {
    id=0;
    strcpy(name,"undefine");
 }
```

The qualification `student::` is required only if you define the member functions outside the class, usually in .cpp file.

Comment: what is the use of such qualification or when we have to use it

Comment: @user1306088: The qualification `student::` is required only if you define the function outside the class, usually in .cpp file.

Answer (score 3):

It would be correct if definition of constructor would appear outside of class definition.

Answer (score 1):

Similar code:

---

Change from:

```
class Solution {
public:
  static int Solution::curr_h; // ----------------- ISSUE: "Solution::" is extra
  static int Solution::curr_m; // ----------------- ISSUE: "Solution::" is extra
};

int Solution::curr_h = 0;
int Solution::curr_m = 0;
```

to:

```
class Solution {
public:
  static int curr_h;  // ----------------- FIX: remove "Solution::"
  static int curr_m;  // ----------------- FIX: remove "Solution::"
};

int Solution::curr_h = 0; // <------ good here - "Solution::" is required
int Solution::curr_m = 0; // <------ good here - "Solution::" is required
```

---

- This happens because copy pasting `static`s require initialization outside of class, but also requires all the declaration (`int`) too.
- Though it is correct, wish there is a easier/ better way to do the same.